# MYSQL - How to update a value?

Tags: mysql

After selecting the record with the current KEY and PROGRAM, I want to update the 'log_info' field for that CURRENT record, inputting the date/time. However, I keep getting the 'die error' for the update code.

### **ERROR CODE:**

```
"Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string"
(for the "$log_info = mysql_query($query,"UPDATE..." code)
```

### **Snippet**

```html
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM `product_keys` 
                      WHERE `serial_key` = '".$key."' 
                          AND `program` = '".$prog."' LIMIT 1") or die('error selecting');

// UPDATE 'log_info' value to the latest date and time
$time = time();
 $log_time = date('Y-m-d g:i:sa',$time);
 $log_info = mysql_query($query,"UPDATE 'product_keys' 
                                    SET 'log_info' = '".$log_time."' 
                                    WHERE `serial_key` = '".$key."' 
                                        AND `program` = '".$prog."' LIMIT 1") or die('log error');
```

Comment: please stop using `mysql_*` commands as these are outdated, rather look more into thigns like mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line:

```
$log_info = mysql_query($query,"UPDATE `product_keys` SET `log_info` = '".$log_time."' WHERE `serial_key` = '".$key."' AND `program` = '".$prog."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Using `mysql_error()` you can catch specific error of query.

See [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

Answer (score 1):

You have `'` around the column name `'log_info'` and the table name `'product_keys'`. That should be backticks.

Answer (score 0):

update query will be like this

```
$log_info = mysql_query("UPDATE 'product_keys' 
                         SET 'log_info' = '".$log_time."' 
                         WHERE `serial_key` = '".$key."' 
                         AND `program` = '".$prog."' 
                         LIMIT 1") or die('log error');
```

because `mysql_query` function accept `2 Parameters`, `first Parameter` should be `sql query` , `second Parameter` is optional that is `MySQL connection`.

Comment: Check your answer before posting here. As for me can't se any update in your query and OP's query..